# konva.js drag and rotate

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I want to draw image that can rotate, drag and resize.I created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iu1340/esrfydsL/

I can drag and resize

but when I rotate the image，the locations of the nodes are wrong

Here is the code I use:

```js
  var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('Image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();
    
        var rotateFlage = false;
        var dir =0;
        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                rotateFlage=true;
            var diffx = Math.abs(topRight.getX()-topLeft.getX());
            var diffy = Math.abs(topRight.getY()-topLeft.getY());
            var dir=180*Math.atan(diffy/diffx)/(Math.PI);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }

        image.position(topLeft.position());
    
        if(rotateFlage){
         image.rotation(dir);
        }
        else{
          var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
          var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
         if(width && height) {
            image.width(width);
            image.height(height);
         }
        }
    }
    function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Konva.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
            update(this);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
            group.setDraggable(true);
            layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.setStrokeWidth(4);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            this.setStrokeWidth(2);
            layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
    }

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
        width: 200,
        height: 137
    });

    var darthVaderGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 180,
        y: 50,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');
    
    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.onload = function() {
        darthVaderImg.image(imageObj1);
        layer.draw();
    };
    imageObj1.src = 'http://konvajs.github.io/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution answer per se.

But you need some set of objects to handle resizing. You need another separate object to handle rotation.

Follow the pattern you'd normally see in ms word or other similar programs.

[image]

The nodes at the corners and the midpoint of edges serve the function of scaling/stretching the image...the arrow thingy is meant for rotation.